# Proving integrality of the coefficients "inside the box"

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory

Consider the (usual) $ABKL$ setting: $A$ is an integral domain with field of fractions $K$, $L/K$ is an algebraic field extension, and $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$ (we are not assuming that $A$ is integrally closed).

The usual proof that the minimal polynomial $p$ over $K$ of an element $a\in B$ has coefficients in $B$ runs as follows: the roots of $p$ are precisely the $K$-conjugates of $a$, that is, they are of the form $\sigma(a)$, where $\sigma:L\to\overline L$ is a field homomorphism with $\sigma\bigl|_K=\mathrm{id}_K$, being $\overline L$ a fixed algebraic closure of $L$. If $q$ is a monic polynomial with coefficients in $A$ such that $q(a)=0$, then applying $\sigma$ as before to this equality we obtain $0=\sigma\bigl(q(a)\bigr)=q\bigl(\sigma(a)\bigr)$, which shows that all the roots of $p$ are integral over $A$. Since the coefficients of $p$ are polynomials in these roots and integrality is preserved under sums and products, it follows that the coefficients of $p$, which are in $L$ by definition, are integral over $A$, so they are in $B$.

It is not necessary to consider $\overline L$, it is suffices to consider a normal closure $M/K$ of $L/K$. Still, this reasoning forces us to exit of our ambient $L$. I want to know if there is a proof of this fact relying solely on the field structure of $L$ and the properties of integral closure.

Comment: Good question. I didn't know the term "ABKL setting", is this standard?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg It seems that "not at all". Professor Robert Ash uses this term in his book [*A Course In Algebraic Number Theory*](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/ANT.html) (see Section 2.2.1).

Comment: Actually it is $AKLB$.